# Reordering OrderedDict

Tags: python, hash-map

Goal: create a new `OrderedDict` instance's keys in such way that keys in the specified order list appear first. If some keys in order list are not present in `OrderedDict`, ignore them.

Additionally, reordering should be "stable", that is, if some keys were not specified in order list, they should keep their original order from the old `OrderedDict`.

In other words:

```
o = OrderedDict([('a',1), ('b',2), ('d', 5), ('c',3), ('f', 6)])
reorder_ordereddict(o, ['c', 'a', 'x'])
```

produces:

```
OrderedDict([('c', 3), ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 5), ('f', 6)])
```

Code:

```
def reorder_ordereddict(od, new_key_order):
    odkeys = od.keys()
    fullorder = [x for x in new_key_order if x in odkeys]
    remaining = [x for x in odkeys if not x in fullorder]
    fullorder.extend(remaining)
    newod = OrderedDict([(k,None) for k in fullorder])
    newod.update(od)
    return newod
```

Any better ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it to this:

```
def reorder_ordereddict(od, new_key_order):
    new_od = OrderedDict([(k, None) for k in new_key_order if k in od])
    new_od.update(od)
    return new_od
```

The first line establishes the required key order, being careful not to introduce keys that don't already exist.

The second line takes care of the rest.  The existing keys not explicitly mentioned should come out in the correct order when `update()` iterates through the keys of `od`.